# Dynamic exceptions class with module-level __getattr__

Tags: python

I have the following `__init__.py`:

```py
import sys

from oreo import ModuleCaller

from bakery.frosting import frosting
from bakery.milcery import milcery
from bakery.order_cancelled import OrderCancelled


class bakery(ModuleCaller):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args or kwargs:
            return milcery(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return milcery

    def __getattr__(self, program_):
        if program_.startswith("_"):
            raise AttributeError(program_)
        else:
            try:
                if program_ in ("frosting", "OrderCancelled"):
                    return eval(program_)
                elif program_.startswith("OrderCancelled"):
                    return getattr(OrderCancelled, program_)
                else:
                    return milcery(program_=program_)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e.__class__(e) from e

    bakery = __call__
    __all__ = [var for var in vars() if var not in ("__qualname__",)]


sys.modules[__name__] = bakery()
```

The following chunk of `milcery.py`:

```py
raise getattr(
    OrderCancelled, f"OrderCancelled_{output.returncode}"
)("...")
```

And the following `order_cancelled.py`:

```py
class MetaCancelled(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        return type(attr, (cls,), dict(__hash__=lambda self: attr.split("_")[1]))


class OrderCancelled(Exception, metaclass=MetaCancelled):
    pass
```

I'm trying to import a custom exception using these two, and raise it in `milcery.py`, but while importing and raising the exceptions work just fine, I can't catch the exception raised even when they seem to be the same exception (`OrderCancelled_1`):

```py
from bakery import OrderCancelled_1
from pytest import fixture

class TestError:
    @fixture
    def ls(self, scope="class"):
        import bakery

        return bakery(program_="ls", j=True)

    def test_OrderCancelled(self, ls):
        try:
            ls()
        except OrderCancelled_1:
            pass
```